# Issue about openXML SDK

Tags: openxml-sdk

I have a picture and I want to put it in the excel cell (so that left upper corner picture lays on left upper corner cell) with specific coordinate. But I haven't got  absolute cell coordinate. I have known excel's coordinate (for example G120) only.
I have tried calculate absolute coordinate through other cell, but I have got significant error.
How do I calculate exactly absolute coordinate through Excel's coordinate?

Thanx in advance for the helping hand.

Comment: When you say "coordinate", you mean the XY position (in pixels, for instance) of the cell?

Comment: @ssyladin
Picture's location sets in absolute coordinate:
<code>DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Position _position = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Position() {X=posX, Y=posY};</code>
Cell location sets in cell's coordinate:
<code>Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.CellReference = "G120";</code>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `AbsoluteAnchor` class?